# Upload arquivo via FTP - PHP

Tags: php, servidor, upload, file-upload, ftp

Eu estou tentando fazer o upload de arquivos para uma pasta específica do meu servidor da Hostgator, porém eu coloco o caminho exato da pasta e o arquivo não aparece na pasta que setei o caminho, ela aparece na pasta raíz. Segue o código:

'

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 1: Configurações do Envio de arquivos via FTP com PHP
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// IP do Servidor FTP
$servidor_ftp = 'br476.hostgator.com.br';

// Usuário e senha para o servidor FTP
$usuario_ftp = 'hugohs';
$senha_ftp   = 'ajbsistemas2018';

// Extensões de arquivos permitidas
$extensoes_autorizadas = array( '.exe', '.jpg', '.mp4', '.mkv', '.txt', '.png' );

// Caminho da pasta FTP
$caminho = '/public_html/Video';

/* 
Se quiser limitar o tamanho dos arquivo, basta colocar o tamanho máximo 
em bytes. Zero é ilimitado
*/
$limitar_tamanho = 0;

/* 
Qualquer valor diferente de 0 (zero) ou false, permite que o arquivo seja 
sobrescrito
*/
$sobrescrever = 0;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 2: Configurações do arquivo
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Verifica se o arquivo não foi enviado. Se não; termina o script.
if ( ! isset( $_FILES['arquivo'] ) ) {
    exit('<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Nenhum arquivo enviado! </p>');
}

// Aqui o arquivo foi enviado e vamos configurar suas variáveis
$arquivo = $_FILES['arquivo'];

// Nome do arquivo enviado
$nome_arquivo = $arquivo['name'];

// Tamanho do arquivo enviado
$tamanho_arquivo = $arquivo['size'];

// Nome do arquivo temporário
$arquivo_temp = $arquivo['tmp_name'];

// Extensão do arquivo enviado
$extensao_arquivo = strrchr( $nome_arquivo, '.' );

// O destino para qual o arquivo será enviado
$destino = $caminho . $nome_arquivo;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 *  Parte 3: Verificações do arquivo enviado
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* 
Se a variável $sobrescrever não estiver configurada, assumimos que não podemos 
sobrescrever o arquivo. Então verificamos se o arquivo existe. Se existir; 
terminamos aqui. 
*/

if ( ! $sobrescrever && file_exists( $destino ) ) {
    exit('<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Arquivo já existe. </p>');
}

/* 
Se a variável $limitar_tamanho tiver valor e o tamanho do arquivo enviado for
maior do que o tamanho limite, terminado aqui.
*/

if ( $limitar_tamanho && $limitar_tamanho < $tamanho_arquivo ) {
    exit('<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Arquivo muito grande. </p>');
}

/* 
Se as $extensoes_autorizadas não estiverem vazias e a extensão do arquivo não 
estiver entre as extensões autorizadas, terminamos aqui.
*/

if ( ! empty( $extensoes_autorizadas ) && ! in_array( $extensao_arquivo, $extensoes_autorizadas ) ) {
    exit('<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Tipo de arquivo não permitido. </p>');
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------*
 * Parte 4: Conexão FTP
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Realiza a conexão
$conexao_ftp = ftp_connect( $servidor_ftp );

// Tenta fazer login
$login_ftp = @ftp_login( $conexao_ftp, $usuario_ftp, $senha_ftp );

// Se não conseguir fazer login, termina aqui
if ( ! $login_ftp ) {
    exit('Usuário ou senha FTP incorretos.');
}

// Envia o arquivo
if ( @ftp_put( $conexao_ftp, $destino, $arquivo_temp, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
    // Se for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo '<br> <p class="alert alert-success d-flex justify-content-center"> Arquivo enviado com sucesso! </p>';
} else {
    // Se não for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo '<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Erro ao enviar arquivo! </p>';
}

// Fecha a conexão FTP
ftp_close( $conexao_ftp );'
```

O arquivo retorna mensagem de envio com sucesso, porém ele em vez de aparecer na pasta "softwares", ele aparece na pasta "public_html".

[image: Segue abaixo a imagem do caminho dentro do servidor]

Tem alguma solução para esse problema ?

Comment: Não tem o resto do código na sua pergunta para verificar se concatenou uma barra no caminho mas acho que falta uma `/`  nesse caminho `**$caminho = '/public_html/softwares/';**` ou mais adiante no código

Comment: Coloquei o restante do código PHP agora, seria isso ?

Comment: fiz isso que você comentou e deu certo, anteriormente tinha feito e não tinha dado certo, obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na figura a pasta a ser considerada é  `software` e no código está `Video` mas isso não tem importancia, vou considerar como sendo na pasta `Video`

> Supondo que o valor da variável `$nome_arquivo` seja `imagem1.jpg`

Sabemos que o valor da variável `$caminho` é `/public_html/Video`

concatenando as duas variáveis, para atribuir esse valor a variável `$destino`  temos como resultado `/public_html/Videoimagem1.jpg`

o que explica o porque está sendo salvo na raiz.

Portando a solução é dada no comentário do @LeoCaracciolo

$caminho = `/public_html/Video/`

sendo assim; `$destino=/public_html/Video/imagem1.jpg`

Comment: Entendi, exatamente isso que estava acontecendo, obrigado pela explicação